# MappingJacksonJsonView return top-level json object

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I converted to controller to use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver instead of MessageConverters to support multiple output types.  With json, I am using MappingJacksonJsonView:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>                         
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

With the following controller logic:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getById(@PathVariable (value="id") String id) {
    MyObject ret = doGetById(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("common/single");
    modelAndView.addObject("myObject", ret);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

The json return when I access /id/1234.json is something like:

```
{
   myObject: {
        field1:"abc",
        field2:"efg"
   }
}
```

Is there a way for my to set myObject as the top level node for the result so it look like this instead:

```
{
    field1:"abc",
    field2:"efg"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's happening is Spring MVC is taking the ModelAndView and serializing it to JSON.  Since a ModelAndView just looks like a map, and in this case, you only have one entry in the map with a key name of myObject, that's what the JSON response looks at.  In order to get just your object, you need to return just your object instead of a ModelAndView and let Jackson serialize your object to JSON.

Rather than returning a ModelAndView, return a MyObject and annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`, so your controller method becomes

```
@RequestMapping(value="/id/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponeBody MyObject getById(@PathVariable (value="id") String id) {
    return doGetById(id);
}
```

Comment: Ah, sometime simple is the best way.  I was hoping to use the same controller for html view (hence returning ModelAndView), but it makes sense to just create another function for that.

Comment: Superb, i found the solution of my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037473/spring-mvc-modelandviewcontainer-view-is-null-default-modelsome-object

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and following solution works for me.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
   <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. From the documentation: "The effect of setting this flag is similar to using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter with an @ResponseBody request-handling method."

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to remove the outer node by using [`MappingJacksonJsonView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel%28boolean%29):

> Set whether to serialize models containing a single attribute as a map
>   or whether to extract the single value from the model and serialize it
>   directly.
>
> The effect of setting this flag is similar to using
>   MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter with an @ResponseBody
>   request-handling method.

For example:

```
private final MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();

public MyController() {
     view.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getById(@PathVariable (value="id") String id) {
    MyObject ret = doGetById(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setView(this.view);
    modelAndView.addObject("myObject", ret);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This should also work if you prefer to do it via configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="extractValueFromSingleKeyModel" value="true" />
</bean>
```