# Jackson Collection<Object> attributes to top level JSON output string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson in order to have log outputs as JSON.
The things is that we allow logging with the following syntax:

```
log.info("yourMessage {}", innerMessageObject, Meta.of("key", ObjectValue))
```

**OUTPUT I HAVE**

```
{
  "level": INFO,
  ... classic logging attributes
  "metadata": {
     "object1": "value 1",
     "object2": { ... }
     ...
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT I WANT**

```
{
  "level": INFO,
  ... classic logging attributes
  "object1": "value 1",
  "object2": { ... }
   ...
}
```

**My log POJO**

```
@Data
class JsonLog {
  @JsonIgnore
  private static final ObjectMapper mapper = JsonLog.initMapper();

  private final String message;
  private final String class_name;
  private final Collection<Object> metadata;
  private final Marker marker;
  private final String level;
  private final Long timestamp;
  private final String thread;
  private final String logger;
  private final LoggerContextVO logger_context;
  private final Map<String, String> environment_vars;
}
```

I don't succeed to only have the `metadata` attribute to be serialized as top level attributes.

It seems I cannot use `@JsonUnwrapped` because of [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171), I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513133/mappingjacksonjsonview-return-top-level-json-object) but cannot see how to implement it.

Have you got any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be OK to convert `metadata` to be `Map<String, Object>`? It seems so by you example JSON and that's actually the natural generic representation of JSON in Java. In that case:

```
private final Map<String, Object> metadata;

@JsonAnyGetter
Map<String, Object> getMetadata() {
    return metadata;
}
```

According to the [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html), this annotation marks the getter method:

> to be serialized as part of containing POJO (similar to unwrapping)

and can only be used with methods returning a `Map`. I am not aware of a solution for `Collection`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it requires some modifications but I'll give it a try !